# Set Value on Custom WooCommerce Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field

Hopefully a simple one for those of you in the know.  I've created a custom field that I display on WooCommerce Checkout billing information.

```
function reigel_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields = array() ) {

$checkout_fields['billing']['order_birth_date'] = array(
     'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'id'            => 'datepicker',
    'required'      => false,
    'name'          => 'jqueryDate',
    'maxlength'     => '8',
    'label'         => __('Date of Birth'),
    'placeholder'       => __('MM/DD/YY'),
    'options'     =>   $mydateoptions,
     'value'            => 'test'
    );

return $checkout_fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reigel_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
```

That all works lovely.

However, it doesn't seem that I can pass "value" into the array.  It just doesn't show up.  I want to set a default value to the custom field, but I can't work out how to do it. :(

Comment: Please clarify 'pass "value" into the array'? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Tom got it, the 'value' that is usually assigned to a field that you want to have a value before the user has input anything is called 'default' in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add `'default' => 'Default Value'` to your order_birth_date array.

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this managed to solve one of my other questions I had regarding a custom Country Selector on the registration page!